# How to extract a possible closed form from WolframAlpha[] output

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, boxes, wolfram-alpha-queries

To find a possible closed form of a number, I can use the function

```
WolframAlpha["6.38905609893065", IncludePods -> "PossibleClosedForm"]
```

It returns a result in the following form:

[image: Possible closed forms]

The `InputForm` of this result displays quite a large expression containing pods and cells represented as `XMLElement`s.

> Is there an easy way to extract the first suggested closed form as a normal expression (in this case, `E^2 - 1`)?

Comment: is this "easy"? `WolframAlpha[
  "6.38905609893065", {{"PossibleClosedForm", 1}, 
   "FormulaData"}][[1, 1]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you attack this: First click on the little "+" in the right upper corner. Then you select either "Subpod content" or directly "Formula data". Both will result in a more specific request which gives you the hint you need:

```
{WolframAlpha[
  "6.38905609893065", {{"PossibleClosedForm", 1}, "FormulaData"}], 
 WolframAlpha[
  "6.38905609893065", {{"PossibleClosedForm", 2}, "FormulaData"}], 
 WolframAlpha[
  "6.38905609893065", {{"PossibleClosedForm", 3}, "FormulaData"}]}
```

From this, it is only one step to

```
WolframAlpha[
  "6.38905609893065", {{"PossibleClosedForm", 1}, "FormulaData"}] /. 
 Hold[expr_ ≈ _] :> expr
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful. Unfortunately, it does not handle cases like `9.4536360064616926`. In this case _WolframAlpha_ returns $\frac{L^4}5$ with a comment that $L$ is the [lemniscate constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html). The `FormulaData` in this case is `$Failed`, while ideally it would be `Gamma[1/4]^8/(320 π^2)`.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yes, this is very unfortunate, although I kind of expected that this does not work for every possible example. WolframAlpha is more a tool for a *human user*.